# ViewCon USB-Midi device not working in Windows 11

Tags: midi

As a musician, I use MIDI In/Out a lot on my instruments.
Until last week, I had CuBase and a ViewCon USB/Midi I/O installed on a Notebook running in Windows 7 (without any problem).
But the Notebook died (BSOD) and I decided to replace it
Got a brand new Notebook with Windows 11 installed and came to the conclusion that the VIEWCON USB/MIDI I/O is not supported anymore.
Looked up in Google, and found that a lot of users was having the same problem.
Tried a few answers, but at no aval.
Can anybody help me with this?
VIEWCON shows up in the DEVICES list, but with an Exclamation and "Not Running"

Comment: This is a question better suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) since StackOverflow is primarily for developers and programming related questions.